# Graph a vector function

Tags: calculus, vectors

> graph $$V(t)=t\hat{i}+t\hat{j}+t^2\hat{k}$$

So We need to get rid of the parameter $t$ and find the scalar function $f(x,y,z)$.

So we have $x=t,y=t,z=t^2$ to get rid of $t$ we will use the equation:

$\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}=z\Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{(\sqrt{2})^2}+\frac{y^2}{(\sqrt{2})^2}=\frac{z}{1}$

So for $-\infty \leq t \leq \infty$ the vector function $V(t)=t\hat{i}+t\hat{j}+t^2\hat{k}$ lays in the graph of $\frac{x^2}{(\sqrt{2})^2}+\frac{y^2}{(\sqrt{2})^2}=\frac{z}{1}$$ which is an lliptic paraboloid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't the answer a parabola, not a paraboloid? 
Let's think of this graph as a parametric equation:
$$\left(t,t,t^2\right)$$
We can see that this is a parabola mapped on the plane $y=x$:

[image]

Comment: So it is contained in a paraboloid but the vector equation is a parabola because for every $t$, $x=y=z^2$?

Comment: @gbox Yep, pretty much. The vector equation satisfies the equation you originally proposed, so it is contained within the paraboloid. However, that does not necessarily mean that the graph itself is the paraboloid.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. The graph will be contained in the (circular) paraboloid. Note that it is circular because, for a fixed z, you get equations of circles.

Now, you would necessarily have to say this because the graph of the vector function by definition is
$$
\{(t,t,t^2) : t\in \mathbb{R}\}.
$$
That is, you get the parabola obtained by intersecting the paraboloid with the plane $x = y$.

Comment: Wouldn't the answer be a parabola, not a paraboloid? For any given $z$ value, there is only one corresponding $x$ and $y$ value (namely $\sqrt{z}$)

Comment: I think that actually the graph $V(t)=t\hat{i}+t\hat{j}+t^2\hat{k}$ is not the same as $\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2=z$. It is true that, however, the graph $V(t)=t\hat{i}+t\hat{j}+t^2\hat{k}$ is contained within the graph  $\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2=z$. Think about it this way: the graph $V(t)=t\hat{i}+t\hat{j}+t^2\hat{k}$ is the same as the parametric equation $(t,t,t^2)$, which is a parabola on the plane $y=x$.

Comment: @Hrhm: I updated. Thanks.